# extract date from a txt file using shell script

Tags: shell

I have a file that has text value like below.

```
+-----------+
| d_date      |
+-----------+
| 2021-08-01|
+-----------+
```

Need to set the date into a variable. Like d_date=2021-08-01
So, It can be used in a shell script.
date_end=${d_date}

Comment: This looks like the nicely-formatted (i.e. intended for human consumption) output of a SQL query. If so, there are usually much easier and more robust solutions to avoid the formatting and to just get the raw date. Therefor the question: how did you generate this text file?

Comment: I had to run a select query using "hive -f query.sh > a.txt" cmd. It generates an output like above.

Comment: The `hive` command has a `-S` flag which should cause it to not emit any formatting or status messages. With this flag added, you should get your desired output directly, e.g. `date_end="$(hive -f query.sh -S)"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't given more information on the exact file format except that example:

```
date_end=$(tail -n 2 file.txt|head -n 1|tr -cd '[0-9-]')
```

(assuming that the input is stored in *file.txt*).